# Sub menu item on drop down any device other than desktop does not work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a development site at:

```
http://www.dinewine.com/startbootstrap-agency-1.0.6/index.html
```

When I try to use the hamburger menu on any device other than a desktop, the hamburger menu opens, but the sub items do not display when the glyphicon is clicked, the drop down menu closes.

I am not really sure where to start here. I checked the developer site and they are not using drop down menus.

Any information would be appreciated. Thanks so much. -Beth

My code for the drop down with a sub drop down is:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown">Special Events<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.dinewine.com/special_event.pdf"   target="_blank">Rehersal Dinners</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Without a sub menu:

```
<li>
  <a class="page-scroll" href="http://www.opentable.com/grahams-at-squaw-  valley-reservations-olympic-valley?rid=93322&restref=93322"     target="_blank">Reservations</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: can you please add your code here or in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i had to guess it is probably because of your script that closes the responsive menu when you click a link.  I see that you have the class of `.page-scroll` on every link that scrolls to anchors on the page so just add that to the class selector that closes the responsive menu.

The below jquery script is in your agency.js file on the bottom just add the class of `.page-scroll` to the jquery selector like so and also remove the class of `.page-scroll` from any of the links that activate the dropdown-menu because you are obviously not going to scroll the page when you are just trying to open a dropdown menu so in the christy lodge link remove the class of `.page-scroll` from the dropdown-toggle link. After these changes it should probably fix the problem.

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a.page-scroll').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

Also I noticed in your above html markup you forgot to add the class="dropdown-toggle" to your `<a>` tag and just put dropdown-toggle.  It reads

```
<a href="#" dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown">Special Events<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

And it should read:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Special Events<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

In the source code on your website the Christy lodge dropdown link is correct but the Special events link has this error.  Dont think it has much effect but figured I would let you know.

And also im not sure if your aware but you have linked to bootstraps javascript file twice and I believe it is causing errors in your console so you may want to remove the link to bootstraps javascript file in your head section.

Comment: Hello Drinkin People - That worked perfectly. I removed the dupe ref to bootstrap .js. I thought it might be something with the "page-scroll" but I don't know much about javascript. Thank you. Also thanks to Himanshu.

Comment: Hi Drinkin - I put a green check mark next to your answer. Is that how I indicate that yours was the right answer?

Comment: Yep that way other people who have the same issue as  you do can see whtat works

Answer (score 1):

Here is your updated code..

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Special Events<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.dinewine.com/special_event.pdf"   target="_blank">Rehersal Dinners</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I added class

> class="dropdown-toggle"

Now its working smooth. If you want to dropdown menu on hover then go to [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/show-dropdown-hover-amp-caret-up).

If you need drop down menu to show on hover on the desktop and on click for mobile. Then go to [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/cwwaqp5k/46/)

Answer (score 0):

try this, its a hack but should work

in agency.js

```
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
    if($(event.target.parentElement).hasClass("dropdown")) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $(event.target.parentElement).attr("class","dropdown open");
    } else {
         $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
   }
});
```